# How to Convert Importrange cells to hard values using an archiving script without needing to set the source to Public sharing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

So I have a script I cobbled together from various contributors on here which is designed to take values from formulas, cement them as hard values in the cell, and copy the spreadsheet to a new location with all the designated cells' formulas removed (and just the values kept).

Here is it below:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Master Menu')
      .addItem('Archive Report', 'Archiver')
      .addToUi();
}

function Archiver() {
  var spreadsheetId = "File_ID"; // Please set the source Spreadsheet ID.
  var destFolderId = "Folder_ID";  // Please set the destination folder ID.

  // Copy all the spreadsheet (formulas included)
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  var destination = ss.copy(ss.getName() + " - " + new Date().toLocaleString());
  var backgroundColor = "#00ff00"; // The background color you want to check for  
  destination.getSheets().forEach(function(sheet) { // Iterating through each sheet in the destination    
    var backgrounds = sheet.getDataRange().getBackgrounds(); // Getting 2-dimensional array with background colors for each cell in the sheet    
    for (var i = 0; i < backgrounds.length; i++) { // Iterating through each row
      var rowBackgrounds = backgrounds[i];      
      for (var j = 0; j < rowBackgrounds.length; j++) { // Iterating through each cell for that specific row
        var cellBackground = rowBackgrounds[j];        
        if (cellBackground === backgroundColor){ // Checking if the cell background color is the same as the specified one          
          var cell = sheet.getRange(i + 1, j + 1);
          cell.copyTo(cell, {contentsOnly: true}); // Removing formulas from the cell
        }
      }
    }
  });

  // Move file to the destination folder.
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(destination.getId());
  DriveApp.getFolderById(destFolderId).addFile(file);
  file.getParents().next().removeFile(file);
  file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT)
  var datevalue = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(2, 4).getValue()
  var newdate = Utilities.formatDate(datevalue, "GMT", 'MM-dd-yyyy')
  file.setName("LPU Daily" + " " + newdate )
}
```

The problem is, all of the cells whose values I want to "cement" to the spreadsheet use an Importrange function in them, and unless I set the source that the importrange references to Public (sharing), the script does not work and all the cell values respectively are returned nil when copying over. Is there anyway I can get this script to work while keeping the source spreadsheet for the importrange formulas private?

Comment: Tag the language your script is written in.

Comment: What do you mean by "cement". Why are you not using `sheet.getDataRange().setValues(sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues());` to "cement" the values?
Also, please add screenshots to help us understand this issue.

Comment: Sorry, by "cement" I mean replacing the formula derived values with the actual value those formulas produced, permanently in that cell, so basically contentsonly=true. I'll get some screenshots up asap